# Does Spotify allow persistent cookies to be dropped from their desktop app? If so, where does it go?

Tags: html, http

Seeing if it's possible to track ad exposures with ads served on spotify via cookies. Does Spotify share the same cookie store as web browsers? Their privacy policy infers that they can access browser cookies to target ads, but not sure if they allow persistent cookies to be dropped

Source:
https://www.spotify.com/us/legal/privacy-policy/#s13.2